# Subsetting data in R doesn't work

Tags: r

I am trying to subset my data and for the life of me I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Here's a link to my data, which is a csv file [Data](https://outlookuga-my.sharepoint.com/personal/llipani_uga_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=i5tSGumRPa3tw5P61Vi6PLqhgFE2cfRmqc5CB5bNizc%3D&docid=020f9ab4931c24a0cb1258c53050a917c). I've tried these ways to subset, but they all just create a header with no observations.

```
alveolar.df <- combine.df[combine.df$articulation == "velar_coronal", ]
alveolar.df <- subset(combine.df, articulation == "velar_coronal")
alveolar.df <- combine.df[combine.df$articulation %in% c("velar_coronal"), ]
```

Here is a sample of the data -

```
combine.df <- structure(list(start = c(215.76, 278.78, 862.35, 1050.22, 512.59, 
552.97), end = c(217.18, 280.68, 863.85, 1051.72, 515.02, 555.67
), articulation = c(" velar_coronal", " velar_labial", " velar_coronal", 
" velar_coronal", " velar_coronal", " velar_coronal"), hometown = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c(" Montana ", "  ", " San Leandr ", 
" Southern California "), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start", 
"end", "articulation", "hometown"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: just do alveolar.df <- combine.df %>% filter(articulation == "velar_coronal")

Comment: @MLavoie Unfortunatly, this just returns a lot of NAs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have extra whitespace in the column, which is why you are getting all `FALSE` results from the logical expression and hence no rows in your subset. Notice the extra space at the beginning of each string below.

```
combine.df$articulation
# [1] " velar_coronal" " velar_labial"  " velar_coronal" " velar_coronal"
# [5] " velar_coronal" " velar_coronal"
combine.df$articulation == "velar_coronal"
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You actually have this issue in more than one column.  You can do either of these two things:

1. Use `strip.white = TRUE` when you originally read the data into R (assuming you used `read.csv()` or `read.table()`)
2. Use the new `trimws()` function in base R to trim the excess whitespace from the column

   ```
   combine.df$articulation <- trimws(combine.df$articulation)
   ```

   and then try your code again.

The better method would be the first, to go back and read the data in again, using `strip.white = TRUE` since this will assure no extra whitespace in any column.